# Omega-frequency or pulsation?

Tags: optics, soft-question, quantum-optics, conventions

I'm reading a book about optics in English. However, I speak a different language and have a problem with distinction.

What does $\omega$ mean?  $\omega=1/T$ or $\omega=2\pi/T$ What is the convention?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: $1/T$ as in "one over the period" is called frequency and commonly denoted by $\nu=1/T$, sometimes $f$. $\omega=2\pi\nu$ is more appropriately called _angular_-frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\omega$ usually denotes the angular velocity (or angular frequency), its unit is $[rad/s]$. The answer would thus be $\omega = 2\cdot\pi/T = 2\cdot\pi\cdot f$
With $f$ the (ordinary) frequency in $[Hz]$. Of course $f$ can be represented as $f = 1/T$

The physical difference between the two frequencies is simply that the angular frequency denotes how many radians per second the wave would oscillate. The ordinary frequency $f$ denotes how many periods it would travers in a single second.

$f$ has a more intuitive physical meaning and is used in optics to easily calculate the wavelength of the wave.

Comment: But in the book they write "wave of frequency $ \omega $. My dictionary says that in english frequency and pulsation are described with the same word. This bothers me.
Is angular velocity important in optics?

Comment: Pulsation is a word I haven't yet encountered in any academic literature. Though I think I know where the confusion stems from. I edited my answer to try and make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Also, the angular velocity may have been a confusing term to use, angular frequency is a tad more relevant when talking about EM waves. (Though I've seen them be used interchangeably)

Comment: @user46147 Angular frequency is often called just frequency because it's much more useful (in quantum mechanics, EM, etc). You also get rid of many $2\pi$ factors.